# Net::SSH does not seem to connect to remote host

Tags: ruby, unix, ssh, hostname, net-ssh

Following the syntax from http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/

```
Net::SSH.start('remotehost', 'ava') do |ssh|
  puts `hostname`
end
```

It prints the name of current hostname rather than remote hostname. What is wrong?

Comment: can you give the documentation link?

Comment: try `ssh[:host_name]`..

Comment: `puts ssh[:host_name]` does not output anything

Comment: can you tell me the output of `puts ssh.class` ? And what you want to achieve?

Comment: `Net::SSH::Connection::Session`

Comment: Okay try now `puts ssh.host`.. I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use as below :

```
Net::SSH.start('remotehost', 'ava') do |ssh|
  puts ssh.host
end
```

As `ssh` is an instance of `Net::SSH::Connection::Session` class And if you browse the [`documentation`](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/),you will get the method `#host`,which will give you the desired result.

Comment: @ava documentation is very good and descriptive. Give it some time and try to understand the examples given there. You can do,what you are trying to achieve. :)